# XCode: Documents and Library folder for xcode command line builds

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

One can easily build a project run it in the simulator both from the command line like so:

**1,** `xcodebuild -project Someproject.xcodeproj -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator`

**2,** `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone\ Simulator -SimulateApplication PATHTOAPPFILE/Someproject.app/Someproject`

But this way the app have no Documents and Library folders like it would have if it was built by Xcode and put into `/Users/SOMEUSER/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/APPID/Someproject.app`

Ergo `[NSBundle mainbundle]` will not work as expected.

**Question: How to tell xcodebuild where the application should look for its environment folders?**

(By default I believe it searches in `/Users/USER/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/IOSVERSION` but that presents problems, since there is already a Library folder there for other things)

I don't mind if I have to manually create the folders before I run the app in the simulator.

Comment: `[NSBundle mainBundle]` works fine for my freshly-created apps, you shouldn’t need to create anything ahead of time. Maybe you need to ask a question about the problem you have, not a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`xctool`](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) instead. It can run the app in the simulator, re-install it if necessary, all that jazz. And if you don’t want to use it, the source is available, so you can just see how they did it.